# DDD: Can an Aggregate Root be an Entity within another Aggregate Root?

Tags: design-patterns, entity, domain-driven-design, modeling, aggregateroot

I'm trying to model a problem where a *Company* has many *Teams*. There is a business rule that *"the name of the team must be unique per company"*. However, a `Team` has many other behaviours, such as joining. Also, a `Team` can have many `Report`s - which maintain a reference to `Team.Id`.

At the moment, `Team` and `Company` are separate Aggregate Roots. In order to enforce the invariant that `Team.Name` must be unique per `Company`, should I could create a *Team Entity* within the `Company` Aggregate which is only responsible for the creation and renaming of `Team`? I believe `Company` must create `Team` in order to enforce the rules, and be responsible for renaming, but that is all.

My question is: *is this normal? Is splitting a domain concept across Aggregate Boundaries a normal way to enforce invariants?*

The only alternative I can see is to move the entire `Team` Aggregate into the `Company` Aggregate. But in this case, I'll be storing a reference to a non-aggregate within `Report`.

I'd imagine this is a common modelling problem, but Google is failing me!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is team really an aggregate root? I.e. can a team exist without its parent company?

Comment: Nope! I'm really happy to move Team inside Company - but this would mean Report is storing a reference to a non-Aggregate.

Comment: @acairns Entities can have references to other Entities as long as they're in the same Aggregate.

Answer (score 4):

> Team.Name must be unique per Company

Why ? Is that really a domain invariant or more of a technical rule so that you don't confuse 2 teams on the team admin UI ?

If the latter, you should probably let the Application service handle that rule by asking `TeamRepository` and returning an exception when the uniqueness is broken.

Merging the `Company` and `Team` aggregates could be an option, but it seems like a very small domain rule to me to cause such a transformation. Even more so if the 2 aggregates are already big and could cause contention and concurrency problems put together. And with `Report` (presumably an AR ?) referencing `Team`, you can already see that `Team` will likely be a central point in your application. It seems weird to encapsulate it in something else.

http://gojko.net/2010/06/11/udi-dahan-the-biggest-mistakes-teams-make-when-applying-ddd/

http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/10/28/Uniqueness-validation-in-CQRS-Architecture